# Hive UDAF: Casting output of a non-Java Hive UDAF to a map

Tags: python, hive, user-defined-functions, hiveql

I am experimenting with Hive UDAFs written in Python like:

```
SELECT TRANSFORM(id, vtype, price) USING 'udaf.py' 
  AS (vtype STRING, stats MAP<STRING,FLOAT>)         
  FROM (SELECT * FROM foo CLUSTER BY vtype) AS TEMP_TABLE;
```

The python script writes the vtype and some stats, e.g. mean and variance, as a dictionary to standard output separated by a tabulator which works fine. The problem I am having is that I cannot figure out how I should format the field defining the stats mapping so that HiveQL can convert it to MAP as defined in my query. Whatever I tried I got for the *stats* field something like:

```
{"{mean:1.0,var:2.0}":null}
```

In the example above I tried returning it as JSON string and HiveQL interpreted this as key and set *null* as value. Reading the HiveQL docs thoroughly I also tried things like "mean:1.0,var:2.0", "MAP(mean:1.0,var:2.0)", "mean:1.0,var:2.0" etc. but nothing worked. Is there actually a built-in way to do this with Hive on Cloudera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default separators for maps in hive tables are `'\003'` (unicode 0x03) between map key and map value, and `\002` (unicode 0x02) between collection elements (where a map is a collection of key-value pairs).

So, in your case, I would try to either override the table separators using

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':'
```

Which could be risky is you have commas of colons in other fields.

Or you could try to output your map with the default delimiters.

If that doesn't work, you could get a string from the UDAF and turn it into a map using

`str_to_map(text, ',', ':')`

Comment: So outputting `'mean\x031.0\x02variance\x032.0'` in the Python script worked! Thank you. It should also be mentioned that `str_to_map` will work only for `map <STRING, STRING>` so no float keys.